# sub-subclass concept in OWL

Tags: subclass, rdf, ontology, owl

I am posting this on stackoverflow since I am quite confused with OWL right now.

So in OWL file, can I represent a sub-subclass concept?

For example, entities belong to a class called Wine and it inside this class, we have a sub-class called WineType and then Within the WineType, we have sub-subclass called enzyme_avability. Would this be possible in OWL as a nested class concept? (e.g. )

Please help me with this

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  A class X is a subclass of class Y if and only if every instance of X is also an instance of Y.  I'm not sure what an instance of "enzyme_availability" would be, but I'm pretty sure it's not a WineType.  So enzyme_availability shouldn't be a subclass of WineType.

Comment: it is a weirdo example but what I am asking here (this is the crux) is whether we can have sub-subclass

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by that, though. X can have a subclass y, and y can have a subclass z. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: OWL just as RDFS can express subclasses relationships. Example, we want to represent the assertion: `Wine is a Beverage`. It can be represented in OWL as `Wine owl:subClassOf Beverage`, with a formal meaning saying that *all instances of wines are also beverages*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write axioms like:

```
A subClassOf B
B subClassOf C
```

and so on, without limits on the number of levels you want to define. A reasoner will be able to answer queries like: is A subclass of C? by following the hierarchy.
Of course, more complex ways to arrange the hierarchy exist, e.g., the object property restrictions mentioned by Jinal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. I think what you are looking for is here

http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Object_Property_Restrictions

So in sort you are representing a hierarchy structure which is completely supported by OWL.